# Correctness of a multi-language book collection SQL design

Tags: sql

I'm currently designing my book collection software, because I couldn't find any that suits my particular needs, especially when it comes to translations.

Here are my particular needs:

- Books, authors and publishers must be sortable. This can be derived by the name, [but shouldn't](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).
- A book can have several authors and an author can write several books.
- Several authors can have different roles when making a book: a book can have a writer, a translator, an illustrator; a comic book can have a writer, a drawer, a colorer, etc.
- A book can be published by different publishers and a publisher can edit several books: I have books that were originally published by a publisher but a subsequent version (pocket version, for instance) was published by another publisher. Their ISBN are different.
- A book can be translated into several languages: I own copies of *The Lord of the Rings* in English, French, German and Dutch. There must be a link between a translation and the original piece.
- If a book is a translation, I want to have a reference to the original book, even if I don't own any copies that original version.
- I18n is done at the application level so I don't need full labels for the language: only code. Same for the roles.

This SQL is currently a HSQLDB code (because I'm only starting the development), but it will be translated into PostgreSQL (for a server version of the application) and SQLite (as cache from the server version in a mobile version of the application) in the future.

I try to make this database as normalized as possible. My specific questions about this code are the following:

- Does this SQL make sense in regards to my needs? I couldn't find any use-cases that don't fit.
- Is my normalization good enough? I have some doubts about not using a language table for my translations, but then it'd have only the id and the code. Also, it would make sense in such language table to actually use the iso 639-1 (or 639-2) as PK.
- What is more acceptable: using a table translation, or discarding it and placing the book language in the book table?
- I've put many foreign keys as primary keys. Is this acceptable?
- Are my cascades going to make me trouble?
- Are there obvious issues in designing this?

Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
  id          BIGINT IDENTITY,
  title       VARCHAR(255),
  title_sort  VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT book_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE author (
  id          BIGINT IDENTITY,
  name        VARCHAR(255),
  name_sort   VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT author_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE role (
  id          BIGINT IDENTITY,
  code        VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT role_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE book_author (
  book_id     BIGINT,
  author_id   BIGINT,
  role_id     BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT book_author_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (book_id, author_id, role_id),
  CONSTRAINT book_author_book_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT book_author_author_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES author(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT book_author_role_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES role(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE publisher (
  id          BIGINT IDENTITY,
  name        VARCHAR(255),
  name_sort   VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT publisher_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE publication (
  book_id       BIGINT,
  publisher_id  BIGINT,
  isbn          VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  date          DATE,
  CONSTRAINT publication_pk
    PRIMARY KEY(book_id, publisher_id),
  CONSTRAINT publication_book_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT publication_publisher_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (publisher_id) REFERENCES publisher(id) -- no cascade
);

CREATE TABLE translation (
  book_id              BIGINT,
  language             CHAR(2), -- iso 639-1
  translation_book_id  BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT translation_pk
    PRIMARY KEY(book_id, language),
  CONSTRAINT translation_book_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(id), -- no cascade
  CONSTRAINT translation_translation_book_fk
    FOREIGN KEY (translation_book_id) REFERENCES book(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT translation_translation_book_uk
    UNIQUE (translation_book_id)
);
```